# For loop to select two cols at a time using index in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Select 1st and 2nd, 1st and 3rd, 1st and 4th cols so on in a pandas df... until the last one.
Essentially I need to loop over 2 in the following command

```
newdf = df.iloc[:,[1,2]] # loop over the column index starting at 2 ending at the last col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple loop:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    newdf = df.iloc[:, [0, i]]
    # do something with newdf
```

Note that indexing starts with `0` in python, so the first columns is `0`, not `1`. If you really meant columns `1` and `2` (second and third) in you example, then use:

```
for i in range(2, df.shape[1]):
    newdf = df.iloc[:, [1, i]]
    # do something with newdf
```